# Using copy constructors on iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to make iterator. As a constructor I have:

```
iterator(Node* node)
{
    it = node;
}
```

and copy constructor:

```
iterator(const iterator& x)
{
    it = x.it;
}
```

I was told that using first one is not a good idea while having second one(which is better)

I'm not sure how to use second approach in methods like this:

```
typedef iterator<Key, Info> ringIterator;

ringIterator begin()
{
    return ringIterator(any);
}
```

Comment: The first one is not a copy constructor, this is a constructor, and it is not possible to avoid this one. Usualy we declare this constructor private and declare the class Node as a friend of iterator so that it can initialize the iterator to the value of the internal begin node.

Comment: For exemple in [libc++/list](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/list) look how is implemeted `__list_iterator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is a constructor, that accepts a (usually, but not necessarily, constant) reference to the same type.

Therefore, `iterator(Node *)` is *not* a *copy* constructor. It is a constructor from some internal entity of your collection.

You do need that constructor in the implementation of the `begin()` (and `end()` and other methods returning iterators) of the collection. However:

1. It should be marked `explicit` so it won't be used for implicit conversion.
2. It should preferably not be visible outside the two classes. Probably by making it private and using suitable `friend` declaration. You should probably nest the iterator and the internal `Node` type in the collection; that way the `Node` itself can be private (but you don't show the complete structure of the collection you are writing, so I can't say for sure how to put this together).

Comment: I'm doing Doubly-Linked Ring in which Node is private struct. My iterator is in public part of Ring class

Comment: The part you might been interested in declarations: https://pastebin.com/JF65ithW

Comment: Note that a copy constructor doesn't have to accept a const reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza but there are **many** places that assume that a copy constructor will not modify the parameter, for good reasons

Comment: @Caleth Sure, but that is a different matter.